# Button not fired in asp.net 2.0

Tags: button, postback, asp.net-2.0

This is really driving me nut, the page has always been working fine but for unknown reason it stops firing button event! any button's event! All I can recall is I upgrade browser to IE8, but the even if there is anything to do with IE, it's also not working with Firefox.

I checked the generated source code, the button part says:

```
<input type="submit" name="TabContainer1$tpOrg$btnSaveOrg" value="Save" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;TabContainer1$tpOrg$btnSaveOrg&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="TabContainer1_tpOrg_btnSaveOrg" style="width:83px;" />
```

This button is inside a TabContainer.

To exclude the TabContainer's problem, I created another button outside the TabContainer, the generated code is:

```
<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Button" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;Button1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="Button1" />
```

What causes button events not fired here? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a SUBMIT button,
Why then do you need to use the ONCLICK event????

change your button code to

```
INSIDE TAB
<input type="submit" name="TabContainer1$tpOrg$btnSaveOrg" value="Save" id="TabContainer1_tpOrg_btnSaveOrg" style="width:83px;" />


OUTSIDE TAB
<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Button"  id="Button1" />
```